# Keep getting segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, string

I keep getting segmentation fault when i try and compile this. Do i need a check possibly for even and odd? I know it means im trying to get memory that i dont have but im not sure where im making the mistake. This is C also.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    char str[41], even[21], odd[21], *p, *pstr, *e, *o;

    printf("Enter a string (40 characters maximum):");
    scanf("%s", str);

    *p=str[0];
    *pstr=str[0];

    for(*p=even[0]; *p != '\0';p++){
        if((p-pstr) % 2 == 0){
            *e=*p;
            e++;
        } else{
            *o=*p;
            o++;
        }
    }

    *o = '\0';
    *e = '\0';

    printf("The even string is:%s", even);
    printf("The odd string is:%s", odd);                

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `*p=str[0];
    *pstr=str[0];` Using uninitialized variables.

Comment: What do you think `p` points to when you do: `*p=str[0]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some confusion regarding the initialization of pointers in your code:

- `*p = str[0]` copies the first character from `str` to the address pointed to by `p`, which is uninitialized, hence causes undefined behavior.
- you should instead initialize the value of `p` to the address of `str[0]`:

  ```
  p = &str[0];
  ```

  which can be simplified as

  ```
  p = str;
  ```

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char str[41], even[21], odd[21], *p, *pstr, *e, *o;

    printf("Enter a string (40 characters maximum):");
    if (scanf("%40s", str) == 1) {
        e = even;
        o = odd;

        for (p = pstr = str; *p != '\0'; p++) {
            if ((p - pstr) % 2 == 0) {
                *e = *p;
                e++;
            } else {
                *o = *p;
                o++;
            }
        }

        *o = '\0';
        *e = '\0';

        printf("The even string is: %s\n", even);
        printf("The odd string is: %s\n", odd);                
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it makes sense to me now:)

Answer (score 1):

p has no allocated memory, you can set `p = str` but not copy the char in `str[0]` to a random memory address, since p never allocated some memory where it points to.